# Use a variable from one file into another

Tags: perl, variables, global

I have a variable $x  which currently has a local scope in A.pm and I want to use the output of $x (which is usually PASSED/FAILED) in an if else statement in B.pm

Something like below

A.pm:

```
if (condition1) { $x = 'PASSED'; }
if (condition2) { $x = 'FAILED'; }
```

B.pm:

```
if ($x=='PASSED') { $y=1; } else { $y=0; }
```

I tried using `require ("A.pm");` in B.pm but it gives me an error `global symbol requires an explicit package name` which means it is not able to read the variable from require. Any inputs would help

Comment: This sounds like a very strange configuration. Your `A.pm` has executable code as well as values that you want to acccess externally. Is that code in subroutines? Are you aware that any code outside a subroutine will be *executed* the first time the external code `requires` the file? You need to show us the contents of `A.pm` or we can't help you much.

Comment: Normally, you'd return `$x` from a function defined in A and called in B; this is a much cleaner, less pathological way of getting at the information.

Comment: Yes the above if conditions in A.pm are in a subroutine. Is there a way I could read that subroutine outside to extract the value of $x?

Comment: there is a core module named B - avoid using that name even in examples.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a variable $x which currently has a local scope in A.pm and I want to use the output of $x (which is usually PASSED/FAILED) in an if else statement in B.pm

We could show you how to do this, but this is a really bad, awful idea.

There's a reason why variables are scoped, and even *global* variables declared with `our` and not `my` are still scoped to a particular package.

Imagine someone modifying one of your packages, and not realizing there's a direct connection to a variable name `$x`. They could end up making a big mess without even knowing why.

What I would HIGHLY recommend is that you use *functions* (subroutines) to pass around the value you need:

#### Local/A.pm

```
package Local::A;
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib qw($ENV{HOME});


use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(set_condition);

sub set_condition {
    if ( condition1 ) {
       return "PASSED";
    elsif ( condition2 ) {
       return "FALSED";
    else {
       return "Huh?";
}
1;
```

Here's what I did:

- I can't use `B` as a module name because that's an actual module. Therefore, I used `Local::B` and `Local::A` instead. The `Local` module namespace is undefined in CPAN and never used. You can always declare your own modules under this module namespace.
- The `use lib` allows me to specify where to find my modules.
- The `package` command gives this module a completely separate namespace. This way, variables in `A.pm` don't affect `B.pm`.
- `use Exporter` allows me to *export* subroutines from one module to another. `@EXPORT_OK` are the names of the subroutines I want to export.
- Finally, there's a subroutine that runs my test for me. Instead of setting a variable in `A.pm`, I return the value from this subroutine.
- Check your logic. Your logic is set that `$x` isn't set if neither condition is true. You probably don't want that.
- Your module can't return a zero as the last value. Thus, it's common to always put `1;` as the last line of a module.

#### Local/B.pm

```
package Local::B;
use lib qw($ENV{HOME});

use Local::A qw(set_condition);

my $condition = set_contition();

my $y;
if ( $condition eq 'PASSED' ) {   # Note: Use `eq` and not `==` because THIS IS A STRING!
   $y = 1;
else {
   $y = 0;
}
1;
```

- Again, I define a separate module *namespace* with `package`.
- I `use Local::A qw(set_condition);` to export my `set_condition` subroutine into `B.pm`. Now, I can call this subroutine without prefixing it with `Local::A` all of the time.
- I set a locally scoped variable called `$condition` to the status of my condition.
- Now, I can set `$y` from the results of the subroutine `set_condition`. No messy need to export variables from one package to another.

If all of this looks like mysterious magic, you need to read about [Perl modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html). This isn't light summer reading. It can be a bit impenetrable, but it's definitely worth the struggle. Or, get [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) and read up on Chapter 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

After you [`require A;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), you can then access the variable by giving it an explicit package name like the error message says.

in B.pm:

```
my $y = $A::x eq 'PASSED ? 1 : 0
```

The variable `$x` will have to be declared with `our` instead of `my`.

Finally, use `eq` instead of `==` for doing string comparisons.

Comment: ... as long as `$x` isn't a lexical variable declared with `my`